# Passing a list of dataframes into a function with dataframe as parameter in R

Tags: r, dplyr, split

I have a custom written function to determine the first order derivative of a smoothing function of some time series data with a dataframe as the only parameter.

```
first_deriv <- function(my_data) {
  model <- lm(FDelta0~ns(time, 90), data= my_data) #make linear model, second number is the nth order polynomial - 90 seems to be good for my data
  X <- data.frame(time = seq(min(my_data$time), max(my_data$time)+10, by = 10)) # make an ordered sequence
  Y <- predict(model,newdata=X) # calculate predictions for that sequence
  my_data$dY <- diff(Y)/diff(X$time)  # the derivative of the smoothing function
  my_data$dX <- rowMeans(embed(X$time,2)) # x values for derivative
  
  return(my_data)
}
```

I want to split my large data based on a factor - `ID` - to generate a list of smaller data frames and then run this function on each dataframe, as such. For simplicities sake, I have subsetted my data to just two levels of `ID` which still causes this problem to occur

```
data_split <- split(df_simple, df$ID) %>%
first_deriv()
```

Running this code gives me the following error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 364, 205
```

Using dplyr yields similar problem

```
test <- df_simple %>%
+   group_by(ID) %>%
+   first_deriv()
Error in `$<-`:
! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 569 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 364 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 364 to size 569.
```

I understand the problem is being caused by the number of rows in each data frame being different, however I don't understand why this is a problem. I'm pretty sure the issue is with the fact I am passing a list of dataframes into my function, as it works perfectly fine on a subset of data with 1 level of `ID`, and the dplyr approach seems to show that the `Existing data has 569 rows` which to me suggests the function is being performed on the unsplit data.

I thought maybe I need to use `lapply` however that leads to a different error:

```
test <- split(df_simple, df_simple$ID) %>%
lapply(first_deriv())

Error in model.frame.default(formula = FDelta0 ~ ns(time, 90), data = my_data, : 
argument "my_data" is missing, with no default
```

Any help would be appreciated

My simplified data which reproduces the problem:

```
structure(list(time = c(20, 730, 120, 530, 740, 440, 430, 880, 
460, 240, 850, 30, 750, 130, 270, 870, 230, 470, 140, 650, 570, 
560, 540, 250, 670, 760, 520, 820, 260, 450, 790, 550, 830, 580, 
480, 150, 860, 50, 340, 380, 770, 210, 890, 350, 640, 170, 60, 
370, 780, 160, 200, 360, 810, 660, 590, 280, 70, 40, 510, 630, 
180, 190, 390, 290, 220, 690, 680, 420, 490, 300, 800, 720, 700, 
610, 100, 80, 710, 840, 90, 0, 600, 110, 400, 410, 310, 500, 
330, 10, 320, 620, 780, 490, 240, 190, 580, 430, 80, 480, 600, 
270, 170, 280, 790, 750, 550, 800, 530, 290, 850, 380, 180, 440, 
390, 540, 820, 140, 200, 700, 100, 210, 870, 90, 590, 890, 220, 
830, 840, 610, 810, 300, 400, 510, 310, 260, 460, 450, 350, 520, 
710, 230, 0, 500, 760, 560, 110, 60, 50, 250, 860, 10, 420, 880, 
770, 150, 650, 130, 730, 690, 470, 330, 680, 410, 670, 160, 720, 
40, 70, 120, 570, 340, 660, 360, 630, 370, 640, 320, 620, 30, 
740, 20), FDelta0 = c(0.0950300816075294, 0.051173480531343, 
0.0108561841034075, -0.0851666898318219, 0.0491730039910271, 
-0.00514762821912851, -0.0948613069118215, -0.0143805968667472, 
-0.0631614478883294, 0.119035800091336, 0.0382473244246769, 0.070101066258959, 
0.0323997776145192, 0.00793241069832977, 0.09933880030975, 0.0122411294005525, 
0.0927218394456247, -0.0434644481067459, 0.0871820582570535, 
-0.0582371979429335, -0.0680856978337275, -0.131331533069913, 
-0.110711236423563, 0.0790262692849911, -0.077780314913727, 0.00116156702341016, 
-0.0611609713480135, -0.0311538232432551, 0.0765641443122921, 
-0.0482348152413474, 0.0742559021503874, -0.0477731668089686, 
-0.0680856978337275, -0.0243829795683333, -0.0697784087524568, 
0.158122034032921, 0.0530200742608667, 0.0637918710164226, -0.112403947342295, 
-0.0950151897226137, 0.0265522308043614, 0.094876198796735, -0.0254601592438895, 
-0.0723944165359502, -0.0556211901594423, 0.17366419792308, 0.135809026467844, 
-0.101632150586741, 0.0336308401008676, 0.143964815439906, 0.104109167444356, 
-0.0611609713480135, 0.0793340349065777, -0.111172884855946, 
-0.0517741198896005, 0.0491730039910271, 0.0739481365288009, 
0.10518634711991, -0.115019955125788, 0.0330153088576923, 0.127037706252606, 
0.0796418005281664, -0.0639308619422991, -0.0209975577308724, 
0.00547028572563074, -0.0647002759962666, -0.0542362448622995, 
-0.0466959871334124, -0.0951690725334059, -0.0676240494013465, 
0.0773335583662618, -0.0285378154597617, -0.0294611123245235, 
-0.0513124714572195, 0.0816422770684823, 0.0844121676627679, 
-0.00499374540833414, 0.086412644203086, 0.0876437066894345, 
0.0693316522049937, 0.00408534042849013, 0.0704088318805478, 
0.000853801401821416, -0.0667007525365847, -0.16841729047118, 
-0.137948493934038, -0.105171455234994, 0.00608581696880604, 
-0.102093799019122, -0.0226902686496039, 0.123583768052013, 0.0726563548838723, 
0.000122264628603662, 0.00641050229186279, 0.0616519389731686, 
0.0478324399225175, -0.0635278619512471, 0.0409592499184903, 
-2.39734565885918e-05, 0.0259332866650046, 0.0139052041579561, 
0.0125159423486315, 0.11016642373564, 0.238088188757408, 0.00476532383345188, 
0.0810650447824173, 0.0136492875088703, 0.0170858825108844, 0.0788349139832379, 
0.0428237855046894, 0.0218386202796266, 0.0388022381619068, 0.0470281304539614, 
0.0319290481578797, 0.0711574145106537, -0.0292350309737059, 
-0.0097488061218618, -0.0083961038338354, -0.057349302851882, 
0.0214730250666457, 0.0573013559387049, -0.0751537897240181, 
0.00567931186590204, 0.0602261176425458, 0.0227160487907796, 
0.0393871905026758, 0.0530604514681347, 0.0301376316142765, 0.0983942578776779, 
0.0104320496346448, -0.0198026744788172, 0.00436316909917332, 
0.00301046681114743, -0.0248113288966453, 0.0489292255614581, 
0.0413979641740666, 0.00348574058802135, 0.00842127596325356, 
0.134441945877525, -0.0267124240041425, -0.0452846608235364, 
0.0700606288717141, 0.197580239159203, 0.0419097974722387, -0.0856463723365492, 
-0.00638533016244463, -0.0108090322395047, -0.0433104466734433, 
0.078067164035979, -0.0315382808154812, 0.00582554995109378, 
0.0548153084904397, 0.185917751865135, -0.0138434725072397, 0.0404839761416159, 
-0.0606762192900021, 0.247118390518018, 0.0685251289771967, 0.0151116683607907, 
-0.00572725877907975, 0.0773359736100187, 0.0295161197522109, 
0.0449076782186765, 0.0141611208070424, 0.216115916457298, -0.0758118611073819, 
0.00352230010931954, -0.0875474674440464, 0.0209977512897718, 
-0.0283210429412552, 0.0289311674114419, 0.00388789532229992, 
0.0751058428108404, 0.0468453328474709, 0.0399355833221456, -0.0143187462841142, 
0.0443227258779086, -0.0697795400932086, 0.24320652173913, -0.0362910185842234
), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("POMC_GFP_GLP-1_200nM_12_05_23_p4_Neuron_77", 
"POMC_GFP_SEMA_1_2_2023_p1_f1_Neuron_2"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -180L))
```

Comment: You can apply functions to a list of inputs with `lapply`, `split(df_simple, df$ID) %>% lapply(first_deriv)`. This will return a list of results. `lapply(input, fun)` is equivalent to `list(fun(input[[1]]), fun(input[[2]]), ...)`. Note that you want the name of the function **only** in `lapply`. `lapply(input, fun)` not `lapply(input, fun())`.

Comment: Here's a way to do it with dplyr+purrr: nest the data for each group, purrr::map your regression to each nested data set, then unlist for results. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: I think your `lapply()` had the right idea, but you wrongly _called_ your function via `first_deriv()`, rather than _passing_ it as an object: `first_deriv`.  Naturally, you need some sort of iterator, like `base::*apply()` or `purrr::map*()`, to perform `first_deriv()` on each individual dataset.  Otherwise, you're passing a `list` (of datasets) to the function `first_deriv()`, which expects a `data.frame` of some sort; so it treats the `list` as a `data.frame` and the datasets as "columns", which are naturally incongruous.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregor and Greg have mentioned, my problem was in calling the function incorrectly in lapply.

```
test <- split(df_simple, df_simple$ID) %>% lapply(first_deriv)
```

Works perfectly. Thanks everyone!